# trying to prove that directional derivative is linear

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
  $  differentiable at $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^2$

and let:

$  d(v)=\begin{cases}
D_{v}f(x_{0}) & v\neq0\\
0 & v=0
\end{cases}
 $

I'm trying to prove that d is linear, i.e for every $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^2$
$$d(u+v)= d(u)+d(v).$$

So because of the differentiable at $x_0$, we know that:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+t(u+v))-(f(x_{0})+Df(x_{0})(t(u+v)))}{||t(u+v))||}=0\\\Longleftrightarrow\\\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+tu+tv)-(f(x_{0})+tDf(x_{0})(u)+tDf(x_{0})v))}{||t(u+v)||}=0$$

how can i go on?

Comment: It is linear only when the operator is on the function $f$, not on the directions. If define $d_v(f)$ as what you have, then $d_v(f+g)=d_v(f)+d_v(g)$. With your notation, the operator is on the direction $v$. It is not linear.

Comment: By differentiability, don't you already assumed that $v\mapsto D_v f$ is a linear operator?

Comment: this is what i need to prove... @John

Comment: How do you define differentiability? For higher dimensional case you should use that in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function .